# Como pegar apenas uma linha específica de um arquivo?

Tags: python

Minha dúvida está em como depois de separar as linhas em listas, posso também pegar estes valores e somente fazer o `append` da linha correta (`numero_linha` da função).

Só que também, conseguir pegar a linha inteira, e não somente 10 posições da frase do txt, como está me retornando a linha 0 e 10 posições desta linha.

Arquivo `musica.txt`:

```
Roda Viva
Chico Buarque

Tem dias que a gente se sente
Como quem partiu ou morreu
A gente estancou de repente
Ou foi o mundo então que cresceu
A gente quer ter voz ativa
No nosso destino mandar
Mas eis que chega a roda viva
E carrega o destino pra lá

Roda mundo, roda-gigante
Roda moinho, roda pião

O tempo rodou num instante
Nas voltas do meu coração
A gente vai contra a corrente
Até não poder resistir
Na volta do barco é que sente
O quanto deixou de cumprir
Faz tempo que a gente cultiva
A mais linda roseira que há
Mas eis que chega a roda viva
E carrega a roseira pra lá

Roda mundo, roda-gigante
Roda moinho, roda pião
```

```
 # função para ler, extrair valores do TXT
 def extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo: str, numero_linha: int):

    palavras_linha = []
    
    # le o arquivo com o comando 'with' utilizando o parametro 'nome_arquivo'
    with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:   
    
    # extrair linha do arquivo utilizando o parametro 'numero_linha'
     linha = fp.readline()
     count = 1
    
    # quebra a linha em palavras com o comando split ' '
    while count < numero_linha:
        
            linha = linha.rstrip('\n')
            linha_formatada = linha.split(sep=' ')
            palavras_linha.append(linha_formatada)
                                    
            count += 1 
                    
    return palavras_linha
    
 # chamada de função com parâmetros da linha selecionada
 linha10 = extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo='./musica.txt', numero_linha=10)
 print(linha10) # deve retornar ['Mas', 'eis', 'que', 'chega', 'a', 'roda', 'viva']
```

Comment: Você poderia [edit] sua pergunta e arrumar a indentação do seu código?

Comment: E você chama uma função pra processar a linha 11 do seu arquivo, mas está esperando que retorne a linha 10 (se começar a contar a partir do 1).

Comment: Opa, agradeço @fernandosavio! Já editei e ajustei a indentação.
Sim sim, acabei que passei 11 para vir do 0 mas estou usando um count já iniciando com 1.
Mas mesmo assim, só me retorna [['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva'], ['Roda', 'Viva']]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui:

```
with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:   
    linha = fp.readline()
    count = 1
```

Você só leu uma linha do arquivo (portanto, a primeira). Depois, no `while count < numero_linha` você simplesmente insere essa mesma linha (a primeira) várias vezes na lista `palavras_linha` (já que o `while` incrementa `count` até atingir o `numero_linha`, ou seja, ele roda várias vezes, inserindo a mesma linha).

Então na verdade, se você quer a décima linha, pule as primeiras 9 linhas, e só depois leia a próxima:

```py
def extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo: str, numero_linha: int):
    try:
        with open(nome_arquivo, encoding='utf8') as fp:
            # pula as linhas até chegar na que eu quero (sempre uma a menos do que o desejado)
            for _ in range(numero_linha - 1):
                next(fp)
            return next(fp).rstrip('\n').split(' ')
    except StopIteration:
        # se o arquivo tem menos linhas, retorna uma lista vazia (ou dá uma mensagem de erro, você decide)
        return []

linha10 = extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo='./musica.txt', numero_linha=10)
print(linha10) # ['Mas', 'eis', 'que', 'chega', 'a', 'roda', 'viva']
```

Como o modo *default* do [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) é de leitura (`'r'`), eu omiti, mas enfim, se quiser deixar, tudo bem.

Primeiro eu faço um `for` para pular as linhas do arquivo (se eu passar 10, ele pulará as 9 primeiras, repare no `numero_linha - 1`). Como arquivos são iteradores, eu posso usar [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) para obter a próxima linha. Depois, removo a quebra de linha e faço o `split`, já retornando o resultado.

Também coloquei um bloco `try`/`except` para capturar o [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration), caso você passe um número maior do que a quantidade de linhas do arquivo. Lembrando que faltou validar se o número passado for menor ou igual a zero, pois aí ele sempre retorna a primeira linha.

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/516149/112052) sugere ler o arquivo inteiro e separar o seu conteúdo em linhas, mas eu acho um exagero para este caso, afinal você só quer uma única linha, então faz mais sentido ir até ela, lê-la e em seguida encerrar (isso faz mais diferença ainda se o arquivo for muito grande, pois carregar tudo na memória só pra pegar uma única linha não me parece uma boa).

---

Outra forma de fazer é usar [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice

def extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo: str, numero_linha: int):
    try:
        with open(nome_arquivo, encoding='utf8') as fp:
            return next(islice(fp, numero_linha - 1, numero_linha)).rstrip('\n').split(' ')
    except StopIteration:
        # se o arquivo tem menos linhas, retorna uma lista vazia (ou dá uma mensagem de erro, você decide)
        return []

linha10 = extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo='./musica.txt', numero_linha=10)
print(linha10) # ['Mas', 'eis', 'que', 'chega', 'a', 'roda', 'viva']
```

Lembrando que neste caso, a contagem dos índices começa em zero (a primeira linha é zero, a segunda é 1, etc), por isso eu subtraí 1 ao chamar `islice`.

Comment: Cara que aula acima. Estou bem mais avançado em python, mas este problema ainda não me era claro. Fiquei impressionado com seu código. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Asher Só pra constar, se você quer **só** pegar a décima linha e nada mais, usar `splitlines` (como sugeriu a outra resposta) é - na minha opinião - um exagero. A menos, é claro, que vc precise de uma lista com todas as linhas, para ser usada novamente em outros pontos do código, aí faria sentido. Mas se só quer uma linha e nada mais, usando `splitlines` vc estará carregando todo o arquivo para a memória desnecessariamente. O código que eu sugeri economiza memória, e também não lê todo o arquivo sem necessidade (ele só vai até a linha desejada e depois já encerra a leitura)

Comment: Claro que para um arquivo pequeno, rodando poucas vezes, tanto faz, mas para vários arquivos maiores pode fazer diferença. Enfim, sempre vale a pena se atentar a esses detalhes :-)

Comment: Como sempre sua resposta é excelente e bem completa. Adicionei minha resposta pois achei mais simples de entender pra quem tá começando. :)

Comment: @fernandosavio Pois é, acabei esquecendo do `enumerate`, que bom que vc lembrou :-)

Comment: Honrado de receber tantos feedbacks. Agradeço muito vocês de verdade!

Answer (score 5):

Para selecionar a linha correta do arquivo basta você iterar linha a linha e contar em qual linha você está, assim que chegar na linha desejada basta retornar as palavras que estão nela.

Você pode iterar sobre o contador da linha juntamente com seu conteúdo usando a função [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
def le_linha(nome_arquivo, num_linha):
    with open(nome_arquivo, mode="r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        for i, linha in enumerate(file, start=1):
            if i == num_linha:
                return linha.split()

    # caso não ache a linha, retorna lista vazia
    return []


print(le_linha("musica.txt", 10))
# ['Mas', 'eis', 'que', 'chega', 'a', 'roda', 'viva']

print(le_linha("musica.txt", 11))
# ['E', 'carrega', 'o', 'destino', 'pra', 'lá']

print(le_linha("musica.txt", 999))
# []
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-516162-6333)</sup>

Como eu retorno o resultado assim que encontro a linha, não leio desnecessariamente o resto do arquivo e tampouco carrego o arquivo inteiro em memória, apenas a linha sendo lida.

---

Lembrando que sempre que você itera sobre um arquivo, ele itera linha a linha do arquivo sem incluir os caracteres de quebra de linha ([ver documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)) então é eficiente em termos de memória e rápido.

Comment: Poxa que bacana @fernandosavio, acho muito interessante como realmente existem varias maneiras de atingir o mesmo problema com cargas distintas. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Um jeito mais fácil de fazer a leitura do arquivo é usar a estrutura:

```
def extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo: str, numero_linha: int):
    with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:
     linhas = fp.read().splitlines()
    return linhas[numero_linha].split()
```

Essa função `splitlines()` já retorna uma lista em que cada elemento é uma string referente a uma linha do arquivo. Ele já remove os caracteres de pula-linha (`\n`) para você. [Documentação aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

Com essa nova definição, você pode acessar direto a linha desejada e fazer o `split()` de palavras nela, sem a necessidade do `while`. Assim sua função tem o retorno desejado:

`['Mas', 'eis', 'que', 'chega', 'a', 'roda', 'viva']`

Código:

```
def extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo: str, numero_linha: int):

    with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:
     linhas = fp.read().splitlines()

    return linhas[numero_linha].split()

 # chamada de função com parâmetros da linha selecionada
linha9 = extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo='./musica.txt', numero_linha=9)
print(linha9) # deve retornar ['Mas', 'eis', 'que', 'chega', 'a', 'roda', 'viva']
```

Lembrando que como o índice começa com 0, a linha desejada agora é a 9.

Comment: Agradeço muito pela dedicação em ajudar neste problema. Interessante esta função do splitlines(). Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz assim:

```
def extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo: str, numero_linha: int):

  palavras_linha = []

  # leia o arquivo com o comando 'with' utilizando o parametro 'nome_arquivo'
  with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:
      nome_arquivo = fp.readlines()
  # extraia a linha do arquivo utilizando o parametro 'numero_linha'
      for linha in nome_arquivo:
         if "Mas" in linha:
          palavras_linha.append(linha)

  # quebre a linha em palavras com o comando split, note que o separador é um espaço ' '
          palavras_linha = linha.split(sep=' ')

  return palavras_linha

  # chamada de função com parâmetros da linha selecionada
linha10 = extrai_linha_txt(nome_arquivo='./musica.txt', numero_linha=10)
print(linha10) # deve retornar ['Mas', 'eis', 'que', 'chega', 'a', 'roda', 'viva']
```